# Mongoose - doesn't update item after correcting (validateSync)

Tags: express, mongoose

My post doesn't update after the user has *corrected* their error. For example:

Scenario 1 (works): I want to update a *title* and rename it to something else. Let's say the title was *test* and I rename it to *test123*. The user presses the **Update** button and it works fine (the changes are stored and visible).

Scenario 2 (problem): However, if the user presses the update button and the title is *blank* (no content), it reads that the field is required. The user enters a title of *test123456* and presses the **Update** button again. However, this time, the changes are not saved!

Code:

```
router.post('/items/update/:itemId', async (req, res, next) => {
  const {title, description, imageUrl} = req.body;
  const item = new Item({title, description, imageUrl});
  item.validateSync();
  if (item.errors) {
    res.status(400).render('update', {item});
  } else {
    await Item.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.itemId,
      {
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl
      }
    );
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

I'm using express for server routes, FYI.

Thanks a lot for the help!

EDIT 1: So I just figured out that if I modify the `if` statement to `if (!item.errors) { }` and forget about the else condition, my code works fine even if the user enters an empty title. However, I do like the error message to be displayed indicating that a title must be provided to continue. I'm using *handlebars* as my templating. I'll keep you posted if I figure out the solution.

Comment: It looks like you are not handling your errors properly ... server break down after that error

Comment: Can you add validateSync function to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The ids were different when title was blank and retrying.

```
router.post('/items/update/:itemId', async (req, res, next) => {
  const {title, description, imageUrl} = req.body;
  const item = new Item({title, description, imageUrl});
  item.validateSync();
  if (item.errors) {
    res.status(400).render('update', {item});
    item._id = req.params.itemId; // <-- fixed problem
  } else {
    await Item.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.itemId,
      {
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl
      }
    );
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```